# How to update Android in Java Build Path in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am building an Android jar library using Eclipse, running on MacOS. When I go to Properties->Java Build Path, Libraries tab, this is what I see:

[image]

As you can see, I was building with Android 4.4.2 (android-19). All I want to do is update/change this to Android 5.0.1 (android-21). But I can't figure out how to do this. I already went to Windows->Android SDK Manager and downloaded android-21, I just can't see how to update it on the Java Build Path windows.

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question, in case anyone else is wondering: you go to Properties->Android and set it there (instead of Properties->Java Build Path). It will then magically appear on Properties->Java Build Path

Answer (score 0):

Android Stop to give support to eclipse one year after made Android Studio the official for Android apps :/ Try using Android Studio is good and also can start to practice Kotlin :D

Comment: Sorry, not useful